# VMware Authorization service not running

Tags: virtual-machine, services, vmware-workstation

Today when I tried to start a VM in VMware Workstation 9.0, an error popped up (image attached below) saying "Vmware Authorization service is not running".

[image: ERROR]

I tried opening `services.msc` and tried to run the service but it failed with another error message (error 1705).

Please help!

Comment: have you run the services as admin?

Comment: Yup, I tried running it as admin, I also tried rebooting so that it can run as Local System

Comment: you're better off uninstalling & reinstalling then

Answer (score 2):

Easily solved to me. I just tried to repair it using the setup file (If you use VMware 9.0, you need to run the setup file of VMware 9.0), then just restarted the computer. Log in again; now everything works; both the VMware service and your VMware start.

Answer (score 0):

A [VMware Article on VMware Authorization Service is not running](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007131) gives a solution:

> This issue can occur when the VMware Authorization service is not running or when the service does not have administrator rights.
>
> To resolve this issue, start the service and ensure that it does have administrator rights.
>
> To start the VMware Authorization service or to check whether it's running:
>
> 1. Login to the Windows operating system as the Administrator.
> 2. Click **Start** and then type **Run**. If you are unable to find the Run option, refer to Microsoft article [What happened to the Run command?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-happened-to-the-run-command)
> 3. Type **services.msc** and click **OK**.
> 4. Scroll down the list and locate that the VMware Authorization service.
> 5. Click **Start the service**, unless the service is already is showing a status of `Started`.
>
>    Note: The VMware Authorization service depends on the Windows Management Instrumentation service. This service must be running as well. If the VMware Authorization service does not start, or starts and then stops, locate and start the Windows Management Instrumentation service.

The same article also gives some details about providing administrator rights to the VMware Authorization service.

Comment: If you read the comments on the original question, you would know that I had already tried to run the service as admin. So, this ain't a valid answer. :)